# Clang not detecting stack variable assignment to reference as unused

Tags: c++

I have Clang's `-Wunused` flag set but its failing to detect an assigned (but unused) stack variable.

Below I create an instance of a typedef'd array on the stack, but never use it:

```
class AClass
{
    void func();
    ATypedefdArray& marray; // Initialised within ctor, omitted to simplify example
};

AClass::func()
{
    const ATypedefdArray arr = marray;     // Intentional copy

    // arr isn't used but no compiler error
}
```

No compile error.

If I change the function to:

```
AClass::func()
{
    int x;
}
```

I get the expected unused variable warning/error:

```
error: unused variable 'x' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
```

Why isn't the first scenario detected as an unused variable?

Comment: But `arr` *was* used... its copy-constructor was called, and then later on its destructor was called (either of which could have side effects, even if nothing else was ever done with it)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thank you for the answer. Are there additional Clang switches for usage which would detect what I'm aiming for? A more explicit usage required etc?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with clang's options to be able to give a useful answer about that, other than the obvious "check clang's documentation" :/

Comment: Btw if you put your original comment as an answer i'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: They might figure that such a warning would just be annoying because there are many situations where you would intentionally create an object solely in order to have its constructor and destructor called, e.g. [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Not sure how bothered you are but if you put the answer I will give it to you as you were first.

Comment: @user997112 I say give the checkbox to Jarod42, his answer is better than my comment anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const ATypedefdArray arr = marray;` will call copy constructor, and destructor will be called at end of scope.

if both are trivial, then clang/gcc succeed to detect unused variable [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MY9K8s).

If any are non trivial, they might have side effects, and so are used. they might have expected side effect have some intentional RAII usage as `std::lock_guard`, or unintentional as `std::string`. so no warning [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nMsKvY)